# find top 3 product category by revenue, the challenge is presenting this as comma separated list of strings, in descending order of revenue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query below:

```
select date_trunc('day', ordertimestamp) as days 
, product
, revenue
from table
```

The result is :

```
days       |   product    | revenue

2022-07-10 |   shoes      |  $ 430
2022-07-10 |   chocolate  |  $ 10
2022-07-10 |   shirts     |  $ 3.25
2022-07-10 |   phones     |  $ 500
2022-01-02 |   vests      |  $ 200
2022-02-03 |   computers  |  $ 700
```

I need to put this table in a manner whereby the top 3 product categories by revenue for 2022-07-10  appear on ONE row like this:

```
2022-07-10 |  phones, shoes, chocolate
```

as you can see they appear in descending order of revenue

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
array(select products from dataset order by revenue desc limit 3) as top_three_product_categories_by_revenue
FROM table
```

But I'm not sure if it is accurate

Comment: Which DBMS is this ? mysql ?

Comment: it is postgresql

Answer (score 2):

`row_number()` function to assign number to each row by a group and order .

`rn<3` to get only the 3 top products per date.

```
with cte as (
  select days, product, row_number() over (partition by days order by revenue ASC) as rn
  from mytable
)
select days, string_agg(product, ', ' ORDER BY rn DESC) as top_products
from cte
where rn <= 3
group by days
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2_MVw-WQ)

Comment: Hi @SelVazi , what if I want to use a numerical column for product in string_agg() ?

Comment: Then you will have to convert product column to varchar using operator `::` or function `CAST` as follows : `string_agg(product::varchar, ', ' order by rn asc)`

Answer (score 0):

This code will work on DuckDB but can be easily ported to other databases. The first portion just generates fake data.

```sql
with cte_sequence as (
    select * from generate_series(1,100) as id
),
cte_base_data as (
    select
        id,
        timezone('utc', now()) - floor(random()*id*10000)::int) as order_datetime,
        'product' || floor(3*random())::int::text as product,
        random()*100 as revenue
    from
        cte_sequence
),
cte_top_products as (
    select
        date_trunc('day', order_datetime) as order_date,
        product,
        revenue,
        row_number() over(partition by order_date order by revenue desc) as row_id
    from
        cte_base_data
)
select
    order_date,
    string_agg(distinct product, ', ') as top_products_by_revenue
from
    cte_top_products
where
    row_id <= 3
group by 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others already posted in the meantime:

`ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by the date column over `ORDER BY revenue DESC`, then filter by the resulting row number less than 4, group by the date and `STRING_AGG()` of `product` .

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ psql -af top3list.sql
WITH
indata(dt,product,revenue) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2022-07-10','shoes'    ,430
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-10','chocolate',10
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-10','shirts'   ,3.25
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-10','phones'   ,500
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-02','vests'    ,200
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-03','computers',700
)
,
w_rn AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS rn
  FROM indata
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY revenue DESC)
)
SELECT
  dt
, STRING_AGG(product,',' ORDER BY revenue DESC) AS top3
FROM w_rn
WHERE rn < 4
GROUP BY dt
;
     dt     |          top3          
------------+------------------------
 2022-01-02 | vests
 2022-02-03 | computers
 2022-07-10 | phones,shoes,chocolate
```